# Windows 7 Group Folders by (magic goes here)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have some folders on my local Disk D: and I want to group them to look like my computer:

[image: here]

I found that I can group them by Name, Size, Type etc. But what if I want me to specify the  label marked with red on the Image?

Example: If I group them by name, it shows me something like `A-E (2)`, `F-K(4)`, but I just want to name the label myself. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click > Group By > More > there you can scroll down and "Show" > "Label"

Comment: i've already seen that but how to edit a folder's label? By default all folders have label "Unspecified"

Comment: Interesting, but Label is not an option for me...any idea how to make it show up? Windows-7 Ultimate.

Comment: @KCotreau do you have other options too

Comment: Just Comments, File System, Network Location and Percent Full...when I am in "Computer" showing the drives.

Comment: @KCotreau the options i mention are only available within a folder, there are limited options in "Computer" sorry for the confusion